# How to start kinect v2 calibration and programming on Ubuntu 14.4 using C++?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, kinect, xbox360, openkinect

I am looking for some library which could help me to start working on kinect v2 on Ubuntu 14.4 using C++. I have tried using libfreenect and openNI but there are dependency issues in openCV. I have used following link.
[Link for kinect on ubuntu 12.04](https://sites.google.com/site/3dreconstructionusingkinect/project-updates/Installation-of-RGB-demo-07-on-Ubuntu-1204?pageUrlChanged=Installation-of-RGB-demo-07-on-Ubuntu-1204).

Is there any reference from where i can start working?

Answer (score 0):

That guide talks about Kinect v1. It won't work for Kinect v2.

Instead, try [libfreenect**2**](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2). That's the open source, linux-compatible library for Kinect v2. There's a guide on [how to set up and compile libfreenect2, including an OpenNI2 driver](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/README.md#linux).